# Как реализовать телефонный звонок из WebView?

Tags: android, webview

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityMenuDetail extends Activity {

    ImageView imgPreview;
    TextView txtText, txtSubText;
    WebView txtDescription;
    Button btnAdd;
    ScrollView sclDetail;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    TextView txtAlert;

    // declare dbhelper object
    static DBHelper dbhelper;

    // declare ImageLoader object
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    // declare variables to store menu data
    String Menu_image, Menu_name, Menu_serve, Menu_description;
    double Menu_price;
    int Menu_quantity;
    long Menu_ID;
    String MenuDetailAPI;
    int IOConnect = 0;

    // create price format
    DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_detail);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
        bar.setTitle("Свойства продукта");
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        txtSubText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
        txtDescription = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        //btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        sclDetail = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sclDetail);
        prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        // get screen device width and height
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int wPix = dm.widthPixels;
        int hPix = wPix / 2 + 50;

        // change menu image width and height
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wPix, hPix);
        imgPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(ActivityMenuDetail.this);
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

        // get menu id that sent from previous page
        Intent iGet = getIntent();
        Menu_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("menu_id", 0);

        // Menu detail API url
        MenuDetailAPI = Constant.MenuDetailAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&menu_id="+Menu_ID;

        // call asynctask class to request data from server
        new getDataTask().execute();      

        // event listener to handle add button when clicked
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // show input dialog
                inputDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cart:
            // refresh action
            Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityMenuDetail.this, ActivityCart.class);
            startActivity(iMyOrder);
            overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    // method to show number of order form
    void inputDialog(){

        // open database first
        try{
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle(R.string.order);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.number_order);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        final EditText edtQuantity = new EditText(this);
        int maxLength = 3;    
        edtQuantity.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
        edtQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        alert.setView(edtQuantity);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String temp = edtQuantity.getText().toString();
            int quantity = 0;

            // when add button clicked add menu to order table in database
            if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
                        dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                    }else{
                        dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                    }
            }else{
                dialog.cancel();
            }                   
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Отменить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                // when cancel button clicked close dialog
                dialog.cancel();
          }
        });

        alert.show();
    }

    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
            // if internet connection and data available show data
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if((Menu_name != null) && IOConnect == 0){
                sclDetail.setVisibility(0);

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+Menu_image, imgPreview);

                txtText.setText(Menu_name);
                txtSubText.setText("Price : " +Menu_price+" "+ActivityMenuList.Currency+"\n"+"Status : "+Menu_serve+"\n"+"Stock : "+Menu_quantity);
                txtDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Menu_description, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                txtDescription.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

        try {
            // request data from menu detail API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuDetailAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }

            // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu_detail");

                Menu_image = menu.getString("Menu_image");
                Menu_name = menu.getString("Menu_name");
                Menu_price = Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price")));
                Menu_serve = menu.getString("Serve_for");
                Menu_description = menu.getString("Description");
                Menu_quantity = menu.getInt("Quantity");

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            IOConnect = 1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }


    // close database before back to previous page
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        dbhelper.close();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //imageLoader.clearCache();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

---

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sclDetail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/loading" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="aa"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSubText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="aa"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/alert"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_buy"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Какой метод использовать что бы можно было обратится в WebView:
[image: Какой метод использовать что бы можно было обратится в WebView]

Comment: Сосредоточься и задай вопрос так, чтобы и другим было понятно что именно нужно сделать и в чем проблема.